# Sorting order in legend in power bi

Tags: sorting, powerbi, legend

I tried `subburst chart`

And drag year field and enable legend also from properties, but this shows that legend is not in order whereas `year` field is already sorted in data. I checked it through dragging field in *drop down*

Now how i sort that legend

Check image

[image]

Comment: What's the datatype of the year column you used for legend?

Comment: whole number is data type

Comment: Please use normal donut chart instead of custom one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the three dots on the top right of your visual.
2. Select Sort By
3. Select your column name (Year)

**However,**
It seems you are using a custom visual and not the normal Pie/donut chart. So there is not anything you can do about it. The data shown here are ordered by the value returned for each item in the legend.

Best you can do is to use native charts visual of custom visual.

Comment: @MIRROR Can you post a screenshot of what you get on clicking on 3 dots?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the Year column as number format?
[Column in the correct format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10D00.png)

If you don't, PowerBi will not know how to order.

Then you have to sort descending or ascending as you prefer and sort by year
[sort by year and ascending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM7oc.png)

Comment: means i should changed year from text to whole number ?

Comment: Yes because what you want is sort by number and if you have your year column as text, this probably will not work. This should work, let me know if so!